# Split an edge in two?

Tags: mesh, workflow, vertices, edges

Is there a simple and quick way to add a vertex to an existing edge? I mean in a similar manner (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) like a loop cut for the whole object?

My current workflow is, deleting the edge completely, then I select one of the vertices and extend it via <kbd>E</kbd> shortcut. Is there an easier method to get an extra vertex like:

[image]

Comment: Note that by splitting a single edge that is part of of other faces, will create n-gons or triangles, that might require some fixing later to go back to quad topology.

Answer (score 39):

Select your edge, open the *Edge menu* with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> or the *context menu* (<kbd>RMB</kbd>) as of Blender 2.8x / Specials menu (<kbd>W</kbd>) in older versions and select "Subdivide":

[image]
*Edge menu* in Blender 2.8+

[image: subd edge]
*Edge menu* in Versions pre 2.8

Comment: And after you've subdivided the edge, you can increase the number of subdivisions to add more than one intermediate vertex, and by using vertex slide, you can move one vertex anywhere along the edge. One other thing to be aware of is that when you create an intermediate vertex by subdividing an edge, you risk creating undesirable geometry on the face of faces of which the edge is a part.

Comment: If the edge is not supposed to be equally subdivided, you might find the Knife tool (`K`) helpful as well.

Answer (score 9):

### Extend vertices

Since [2.72](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.72/Modeling) Blender versions, with the command <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> and a vertex selected, you can add a vertex on edge next to the mouse cursor.

Then, by double tapping <kbd>G</kbd> key, you can slide it along the edge.

If you just need one single extra vertex and you are not interested in a uniform object subdivision, there's no fastest way.

[image]