# Subdivide an edge to follow circular shape

Tags: modeling, edges

[image]
Is there a way I can subdivide this so that it would increase the resolution of that edge? I want the new vertices to follow the circular shape

Comment: right click > Subdivide, then in the Operator box, set the Smoothness value to 1?

Comment: did Chris answer? You question is not very clear

Comment: your answer work perfectly, thank you

Comment: It's already enough geometry to work with. Add a subdivision surface modifier on top, done: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/subdivision_surface.html **XY problem** IMHO: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem

Comment: cant, it produces weird results becuse everything isn't quads

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split an edge in two?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35244/split-an-edge-in-two)

Comment: the fact that it's not quads doesn't justify a high subdivision (which won't give quads either), you should create a good topology with less vertices

Comment: I want the new verticies to follow the circular shape

Comment: nvm i got the subsurf working, what should i now do with this question?

Comment: If you have the time, please add a detailed answer on *how you do resolved your issue* in order to help future visitors if it is different to any existing answer. Otherwise see: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Edge context-menu *Subdivide* operation has a 'Smoothness' setting in its <kbd>F9</kbd> 'Adjust Last Operation' panel. If set to 1, that should maintain your circular arc. (I think it's a cubic interpolation, but it's so close you wouldn't notice).

Other tools to consider, from the shipped add-on *Loop Tools*, if you enable it ...

- *Circle*, which will create a regular or irregular circle from your selection of vertices, to fit, or by radius
- *Space*, which will space vertices evenly along an existing edge loop, without changing its shape
- *Curve*, which, given a selection of vertices along a loop, will arrange the unselected vertices in the loop between them, using linear or cubic interpolation.

Answer (score 1):

Just right click and choose subdivide.

Whenever you select two neighbor-vertices and press rightclick - subdivide Blender will insert a vertex in the middle.
If you select more than 2 vertices, Blender will add one vertex in the middle for each neighbor-pair.

Comment: I want the new verticies to follow the circular shape